# Perl Get Nameservers IPs from root server

Tags: perl, dns

I'm trying to write a Perl script that should get the IPs of the nameservers of specific domains, as written in the registrar, as if I wrote for example:

```
dig -t ns example.com @a.gtld-servers.com
```

And took the additional section.

I tried using the Net::DNS::Resolver::Recursive, but all i'm getting is the same IP address for both NS Servers. (At my company we populate the DNS record as each NS is a standalone server, that's why i'm getting the same address).

here's what I wrote:

```
my $resolver = Net::DNS::Resolver::Recurse->new();

my @root_ns = map $_ . '.root-servers.net', 'a'..'m';

$resolver->hints( @root_ns );

my $ns_query = $resolver->query_dorecursion($domain, "NS");

foreach my $ns_rr ( $ns_query->additional ) {
    print $ns_rr->name . " " . $ns_rr->rdatastr . "\n";
}
```

Is there a way, except parsing the dig output, to get the nameservers IPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion_callback instead. This will return all the nameservers.

```
    use Net::DNS::Resolver::Recurse;

    my $res = Net::DNS::Resolver::Recurse->new;
    our %NS;

    $res->hints();
    $res->recursion_callback(sub {
         my $packet = shift;
         for  ($packet->additional){
              next if($_->string =~ /gtld/);
              @temp=split /\s+/,$_->string;
              $NS{$temp[0]}=$temp[-1];

       }
    });

    $res->query_dorecursion('google.com', 'NS');
    map {print "$_\t$NS{$_}\n"} keys %NS;
```